# Set minimum Date in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker, android-date

I want to set min date of my DatePicker Dialog from tomorrow day. Example if today is 30 April 2015, it should start with 1 May 2015.

My code:

```
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        }
    };

    startDate.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    SomeClassName.this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(
                        System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000);
    }});
```

I am facing 2 problems respectively.

1. The date range starts from current date i.e 30 April 2015.
2. Whatever date I choose by scrolling the datepicker, only 30 April 2015 is being set.

Note: the datepicker dialog pops on touch event of an editText Box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the tommorrow date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            return dp;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        }
    }
```

Showing the date picker:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

For more information visit: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker

Comment: I need to change the colour of ok and cancel button . How do I use 
setButton() method on newfragment. @Dhaval Patel

Answer (score 0):

Though the above suggestion is correct, I did it in a different way . Posting the solution from my side.

```
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH+1);

final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    } 

}; 

startDate.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                SomeClassName.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(
                    myCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
}}); 


private void updateLabel()
{
   //Do some stuff
}
```